# Император подписал Отречение от престола в пользу своего брата. Правильна ли употреблена прописная буква?

Tags: орфография, прописная, строчная, грамотная-речь

Видимо, официальное название документа — акт об отречении от престола. Иногда в интернете с большой пишут: Акт об отречении от престола. Если опустить слово "акт", надо ли использовать прописную букву?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я думаю, что в приведенном примере надо использовать строчную букву (это нарицательное наименование): Император подписал **отречение от престола** в пользу своего брата.

Пояснение

Официальное название документа выглядит так: **Акт отречения от престола императора Николая II**, то есть с прописной буквы пишется первое слово документа.
http://doc.histrf.ru/20/akt-otrecheniya-ot-prestola-imperatora-nikolaya-ii/

В текстах возможны два варианта. Если подчеркивается официальное название  (как имя собственное), то пишется прописная буква . В других случаях возможно написание со строчной буквы, если название используется как  нарицательное.

Примеры:

Мы не рассматриваем проблемы подлинности **Акта об отречении** как письменного документа.

В список обнародованных бумаг вошел **акт отречения Николая II от престола**, подписанный карандашом - "Николай". Расписка о принятии на хранение **актов отречения императора Николая II и великого князя Михаила Александрович**а.